# Missing argument for parameter 'dictionary' in call

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsobject

This is my NSObject class file that I am using to populate my collectionView cell. I am fetching my data from firebase and populating the collectionViewCell with it. Xcode is giving this error "Missing argument for parameter 'dictionary' in call" I have tried all I can but I could not figure out what is missing. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
class BusinessCategory: NSObject {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var name: String?
var logo: String?
var featurebusiness: [SampleBusinesses]?
var type: String?
init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.name = dictionary["BusinessName"] as? String ?? ""
    self.logo = dictionary["logo"] as? String ?? ""
}


static func sampleBusinessCategories() -> [BusinessCategory] {

    var FinancialInstitutionCatergory = BusinessCategory()
    FinancialInstitutionCatergory.name = "Financial Institutions"
    var featurebusiness = [SampleBusinesses]()
    //logic


    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BusinessCategories/Banks").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
             let financeApp = SampleBusinesses()
             financeApp.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            financeApp.name = dictionary["BusinessName"] as? String

            featurebusiness.append(financeApp)
        }
        FinancialInstitutionCatergory.featurebusiness = featurebusiness

        print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)

    return [FinancialInstitutionCatergory]

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating you need to include the `dictionary` parameter in whatever line has the error; an example might look something like this:

```
var FinancialInstitutionCatergory = BusinessCategory(dictionary: [String : Any])
```

It's unclear which line in your code has the error; you'll need to include the parameter somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, the line you stated is the one with the error. I added the suggested change but it  shows this error "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any].Type' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>.Type') to expected argument type '[String : Any]'"

Comment: Take out the `< >` ... those are not needed; it should be `dictionary:  ["foo" : "bar"]`

Comment: those were not in the code just in the comment. i changed the var to exactly  what you posted

Comment: It needs real values in there, try this: `let FinancialInstitutionCatergory = BusinessCategory(dictionary: ["foo":"bar"])`. Obviously those aren't the values that go there, so something maybe like `[ name : type ]` might be what you would put there. Regarding your original question though, that is what the error is all about.

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error. But I still can't get the cell to be populated by my firebase database. If you are willing, I posted a more detail statement about this problem here. I'm new to iOS and firebase so I'm not even sure if I am doing this the right way. Please if you are willing you can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354571/use-firebase-database-to-power-uicollection-view

Comment: You're welcome!  I'll have a look, although running short on time atm :)